# cloud alternative for wso2 Pre-Packaged Identity Server and API+Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-cloud, wso2-identity-server

I am now hosting Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0 [https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0] in my own AWS instance.

Planning to move on to managed Cloud solution by WSO2. But I can see independent installatiion of identity server and wso2 api manager. But is there a cloud alternative for idenitity server , api manager combo.

I am using WSO2 idenity server for user management only.keeping users in that. Can it be done in API manager as well? 
What is the cloud alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Cloud uses Identity Server for providing Single Sign On. Cloud has its deployment architecture done in a way API Manager can also do the user management (thats comes with the power of WSO2 platform). You dont need to worry about cloud having the API Manager and Identity Server separately.

IF you are managing your subscribers and publishers, then its an out of the box scenario in the cloud. If you want to store end users of the APIs (i.e. if you are using the password grant type), then you can add a secondary userstore and store the end users in it.

I recommend you to raise these questions via the "Contact Support" option available in the Cloud UI.

Comment: I am not managing sub/pub. Its users of the API which i am storing in WSO2 ideniti server. U mean to say API Manager has a user store? Where can i access it in the cloud api manager?

Comment: I am storing username/password/roles in Idenitity server. And scopes in API Manager.These scopes are tied to Roles in idenity server. If i can achieve the same with API Manager , i am happy to go for it. Please let me know how to do it with cloud.

Comment: This is possible. What you need to do in the cloud is, add a secondary userstore in the identity server of the cloud and add your users to it. You need a bit of help from the cloud support team to do this. After that, cloud support team will make that userstore available to API Key Manager nodes which will take the decisions on scopes etc.